# TCP connection Local push notification ios

Tags: ios, swift, tcp, apple-push-notifications

I implement the local push notification iOS from this example :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/local_push_connectivity/receiving_voice_and_text_communications_on_a_local_network

Everything works fine NEAppPushProvider intercept the message sended by the SimplePushServer but i want to develop my own server to push local notification what is the payload i must call to send notification to the ios application ?

I want to develop a python code server to send notification to ios application when there is no internet connection

I'm trying to do my own server like this :

```
import socket

HOST = "192.168.1.7"  # Standard loopback interface address 
 (localhost)
 PORT = 5061  # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)
 with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
  s.bind((HOST, PORT))
  s.listen()
  conn, addr = s.accept()
  with conn:
    print(f"Connected by {addr}")
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        conn.sendall(data)
```

but when i launch application i'm getting error on xcode :

2023-06-08 17:11:36.199712+0200 SimplePush[2512:1251903] [boringssl] boringssl_context_handle_fatal_alert(1991) [C1:6][0x1068080f0] write alert, level: fatal, description: unexpected_message
2023-06-08 17:11:36.199891+0200 SimplePush[2512:1251903] [boringssl] boringssl_context_error_print(1981) [C1:6][0x1068080f0] Error: 4405097624:error:100000df:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE:/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.cc:728:
2023-06-08 17:11:36.204140+0200 SimplePush[2512:1251903] [boringssl] boringssl_session_handshake_incomplete(88) [C1:6][0x1068080f0] SSL library error
2023-06-08 17:11:36.204211+0200 SimplePush[2512:1251903] [boringssl] boringssl_session_handshake_error_print(43) [C1:6][0x1068080f0] Error: 4405097624:error:100000df:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE:/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl/ssl/handshake_client.cc:728:
2023-06-08 17:11:36.204262+0200 SimplePush[2512:1251903] [boringssl] nw_protocol_boringssl_handshake_negotiate_proceed(771) [C1:6][0x1068080f0] handshake failed at state 12288: not completed
2023-06-08 17:11:36.205180+0200 SimplePush[2512:1251903] [Debug] Control Channel: Connection State - waiting(-9856: peer rejected unexpected message)
2023-06-08 17:11:36.205298+0200 SimplePush[2512:1251903] [Debug] Control Channel: -9856: peer rejected unexpected message
2023-06-08 17:11:36.205386+0200 SimplePush[2512:1251903] [Debug] Control Channel: TLS Error Code - -9856

And console of python show :

python3 test2.py
Connected by ('192.168.1.8', 55165)

and close after client tried to connect

I added             NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads

to info.plist file

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Use the example simplepushserver to create your own code. It shows what you have to send

Comment: i tried but it's very complicated to extract and use this code for my own server, have you a example please ?

Comment: You are responsible for the end to end solution. The push provider extension just makes it possible to maintain a connection between your server and your devices. What you send over that connection is up to you.

Comment: I'm getting ssl error i added some detailed message to my initial question can you look at it please

Comment: It looks like your client is expecting an ssl connection but your server is only providing a non-ssl connection